# I can't raise my legs much while lying on my back

Tags: stretching, muscle-groups

I can only raise my left leg about 45 degrees lying on my back and other leg also not more than 60 degrees or so. I don't feel any pain on my back or somewhere else while doing that. The legs just don't stretch. What do you think this is due to? Shortened muscles? I used to cycling a lot in the past and have chondromalacia issue. I am suspecting it might be caused by shortened muscles and this may be the proof of it.

Answer (score 4):

You're not strong enough to lift your legs any higher than that. Raising your legs while lying supine requires strength in the abdominals and hip flexors.

> I am suspecting it might be caused by shortened muscles

Can you achieve more than 45-60° of hip flexion while sitting on the floor with straight legs and your back up against a wall, as in the following image? If so, then it isn't a flexibility issue.

[image]

Comment: No, I can't. If I am not strong enough why I can raise my right leg more than the other? Another thing is if I push myself to raise my left leg more my knee gets bent.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't sit in the position in the image I've added to the answer? And that you could only achieve a similar seated position if you were reclining back to a 45° angle?

Comment: Sorry, I have understood what you mean now. I can't lean forward much in this position. Maybe 10 degrees most.

Comment: @AndrewHarlan Are you the same person as Ender? If so, we have instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them. But just to clarify, are you saying that you can't sit with your back against the wall and your legs flat on the floor? Or you can't bend much further forward than that?

Comment: Yes, I am. I had started the thread as guest, then logged in with my own account. 

I can sit in that position but I can barely lean forward.

Comment: @AndrewHarlan assuming you mean 10° further forward from vertical, that's 100° of hip flexion, which is a lot more than the 45° you could achieve when lying on your back. That indicates that the limitation when lying on your back is strength, not flexibility.

Comment: Ok. I will keep trying and build strength then. Thank you.

Comment: @Ender please also understand that while strength is most likely the limiting factor in how high you can raise your legs while lying on your back, this isn't actually a problem or something that you should feel the need to remedy unless you have a specific need to be able to raise your legs like that. Not being able to raise your legs high in the air isn't going to cause pain, injury, or anything like that.

Comment: @AndrewHarlan: As I stated above, there's a way to merge the accounts. Without doing so, you will not be able to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### This is a problem of strength in your hip flexors, not your flexibility.

If you can passively get 90 degrees hip flexion with an extended knee (other leg bent with foot on the floor/bench), this is not a problem of shortened muscles. This is the medical/physio test for "shortened hamstrings" (after Janda) and negative of you can do that. If you can sit like in the picture provided by David Scarlett, with a straight back, you passed this test with flying colours.

### What is happening?

It may be that there is an imbalance in strength and/or tension that is limiting your *active* range of motion. If your knee starts to bend at some point, this is a sign that your knee extender (quadriceps) starts to become too week compared to the tension in your hamstrings.  It may be that your Mm. vastus medialis, lateralis, and intermedium (prime knee extenders) are too weak *relative to the tension of your hamstrings* and when your M. rectus femoris is raising your leg (vasti plus rectus femoris form the quadriceps but only the latter also does hip flexion and works hard to lift your leg in this situation), your hamstrings (which are stretched due to hip flexion and also do knee flexion) "win" against the rest of your knee extenders. It means your rectus femoris has to support your prime hip flexor (M. iliopsoas) so much that it fails to keep extending the knee together with the vasti. This would fit with cycling as well, especially as I'd think you used clicks.

### Testing active flexibility of your hamstrings

You can test your active flexibility leg by leg in any given door frame with a plain floor: lie flat on the floor with one leg lying flat through the opened door (knee pit pressed to the floor) and the other one with your foot against the frame (hip and knee flexed) so that your foot can slide up the door frame, half the buttock (test side) in firm contact with the door frame. If you can slide your heel up the frame until your knee is fully extended without your other knee losing contact with (or lifting from) the floor, you got active 90 degrees - which is quite good.

### Increasing active ROM

The upside of that test is that you can use it directly to *improve* the ROM by doing that each day if you fail to achieve both legs straight in 90 degrees: min 10 reps per leg, sliding to as much extension as you can manage without the other knee being lifted, holding in max position for some seconds, back a bit, and to max extension again, holding it there, and so on.

### Long story short

You need stronger knee extensors and hip flexors, possibly also stronger abdominal muscles (for stabilising the torso against lumbal hyperflexion) if you want to raise your legs while keeping them straight. It may, indeed, help to concentrate on keeping your legs straight since it influences muscle reflexes that make this harder to do. Until then, I recommend hanging knee to chest, for example, as an easier exercise for the strength you need.